# Converting Antlr 4 grammar into Antlr 3.5

Tags: php, antlr, grammar, antlr4, antlr3

On searching the PHP lexer grammar for Antlr 3.5, got the grammar for Antlr 4 from [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teverett/phpGrammar/master/src/main/antlr4/com/khubla/phpGrammar/PHPLexer.g4) (which is not compatible with Antlr 3.5).

So trying to make compatible for Antlr 3.5. The only issue of these mode commands e.g.

```
PHP_Start
    : ('<?' | '<?php' | '<?PHP') -> pushMode(PHP)
    ;
mode PHP;

PHP_END         
    :   '?>' -> popMode ;
```

So, My point is how to convert these **pushMode(), popMode() functionality into equivalent Antlr 3.5**??

Comment: Just a curious, why do want to use Antlr 3?

Comment: Another remark: more perfect php grammar exists in an official ANTLR 4 grammars repository: [php](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/php)

Comment: My application is based on Antlr 3.5, so can't used the version 4 grammar available @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teverett/phpGrammar/master/src/main/antlr4/com/khubla/phpGrammar/PHPLexer.g4